# Grouping data in a list of of dicts

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
[{TYPE, OBJECT_ID, ACTOR, EXTRA_FIELDS}, ...]
```

I'd like to go through and aggregate the duplicates of {TYPE, OBJECT_ID} and make ACTOR a list so:

start with:

```
   [ {'type': 'LOVE', 'obj_id': 1242, 'actor': 'bob', {..}}, 
      {'type': 'LOVE', 'obj_id': 1242, 'actor': 'dave', {..}}, 
      {'type': 'FAV', 'obj_id': 1242, 'actor': 'sam', {..}}, 
      {'type': 'LOVE', 'obj_id': 242, 'actor': 'bob', {..}}]
```

end up with:

```
   [ {'type': 'LOVE', 'obj_id': 1242, 'actor': ['bob', 'dave'], {..}}, 
      {'type': 'FAV', 'obj_id': 1242, 'actor': ['sam'], {...}}, 
      {'type': 'LOVE', 'obj_id': 242, 'actor': ['bob'], {...}} ]
```

the EXTRA_FIELDS don't have to be merged, they can just use the data from one of the items aggregated.

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Those object literals don't make sense, they are set literals.  `{a,b}` would give (assuming a and b are defined), `set([a,b])`.

Comment: Your syntax is very unfamiliar, for example what is {TYPE, OBJECT_ID, ACTOR, EXTRA_FIELDS} - In Python its a set but I suspect you don't mean it that way?

Comment: If it's a set, it would become much more expensive. I suspect the op is using tuple, so that what he has is a list of tuples. At least I hope so.

Comment: Is there a good reason you want to have a list of dicts, rather than just a single combined dictionary that maps from a `(type, obj_id)` tuple to a `(actorlist, otherstuff)` tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def merge_dicts(list_of_dicts):
    lookup = {}
    results = []
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        key = (d['type'], d['obj_id'])
        try: # it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission
            lookup[key]['actor'].append(d['actor'])
        except KeyError:
            val = {'type': d['type'],
                   'obj_id': d['obj_id'],
                   'actor': [d['actor']], # note, extra [] around value to make it a list
                   'extra_fields': d['extra_fields']}
            lookup[key] = val
            results.append(val)

    return results
```

The `lookup` dict maps from the a tuple of the key values to the dictionaries that have been included in the results list. Those output dictionaries will have their `actor` value mutated if other dictionaries with the same key are encountered later on.

A rather more natural solution though would be to get rid of the list-of-dictionaries data structure and instead go for a single dictionary that maps from `type, obj_id` keys to `actors, extra_fields` values. Here's what that would look like:

```
def merge_dicts2(list_of_dicts):
    results = {}
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        key = (d['type'], d['obj_id'])
        try:
            results[key][0].append(d['actor'])
        except KeyError:
            results[key] = ([d['actor']], d['extra_fields'])

    return results
```

This has most of the data that your list of dicts had, only the order has been lost (and since you were merging items from the old list, some of that order was going to be lost regardless).

If you're going to be iterating over the collection later, this way is much easier, since you can unpack tuples (even nested ones) right in the loop:

```
combined_dict = merge_dicts(list_of_dicts)

for (type, obj_id), (actors, extra_fields) in combined_dict.items():
    # do stuff with type, obj_id, actors, extra_fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `input` is the list of tuples (not sets), what about

```
TYPE= 0
OBJECT_ID= 1
ACTOR= 2
EXTRA_INFO= 3
keys= set( [ ( e[TYPE] , e[OBJECT_ID] ) for e in input ] )
output= { k: [ ( e[ACTOR] , e[EXTRA_INFO] ) for e in input if ( e[TYPE] , e[OBJECT_ID] ) == k ] for k in keys }
```

Or, if you like one-liners:

```
output= { k: [ ( e[2] , e[3] ) for e in input if ( e[0] , e[1] ) == k ] for k in [ ( e[0] , e[1] ) for e in input ] }
```

Assuming that `input` is a list of dictionaries, this becomes:

```
keys= set( [ ( e['type'] , e['obj_id'] ) for e in input ] )
output= { k: [ { 'actor':e['actor'] , 'extra_info':e['extra_info'] } for e in input if ( e['type'] , e['obj_id'] ) == k ] for k in keys }
```

Or,

```
output= { k: [ { 'actor':e['actor'] , 'extra_info':e['extra_info'] } for e in input if ( e['type'] , e['obj_id'] ) == k ] for k in [ ( e['type'] , e['obj_id'] ) for e in input ] }
```

Of course, you can also write manually what these comprehensions do, but I wouldn't recommend it unless the data volume is too big and you start experiencing performance issues that require low-level optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Your list I denoted as `alist`.

```
actors = {}
extra = {}
for x in alist:
   if actors.has_key([(x['type'],x['obj_id'])):
      actors[x['type'],x['obj_id']].append(x['actor'])
   else:
      actors[x['type'],x['obj_id']] = []
   extra[x['type'],x['obj_id']] = x['extra']

outlist = []
for k in actors.keys():
   x = {}
   x['type'], x['obj_id'], x['actor'], x['extra'] = k[0], k[1], actors[k], extra[k]
   outlist.append(x)
```

`outlist` is the output list.

Answer (score 0):

You should break the problem down into its component parts.

The first thing you need to do is change all those actors to lists:

```
for dict in list_of_dicts:
    dict['actor'] = [dict['actor']]
```

Then you need write a method which checks if a particular pair is in the list of dicts, returning the index if it is:

```
def check_pair(list_of_dicts,type,obj_id):
    #return index of matching pair, None otherwise
    index = -1
    for dict in list_of_dicts:
    index += 1
        if dict['type'] == type and dict['obj_id'] == obj_id:
        return index
    else:
        return None
```

Then you need to make a new list (to store your new data) and go through the old list, either appending it to your new list or, if the obj_id and type are already there, appending actor to that dict.

```
new_list = []
for dict in list_of_dicts:
    j = check_pair(new_list,dict['type'],dict['obj_id'])
if j == None:
    new_list.append(dict)
else:
    new_list[j]['actor'].append(dict['actor'])
```

I should point out that having a list of dicts like this is pretty unconventional stuff, you should really be figuring out a way to make your data structures more sensible.

Answer (score -2):

One solution is: first, get the set of identifiers (a set of unique combinations of type and obj_id); then, get the list of actors for each combination.

```
identifiers = set((item['type'], item['obj_id']) for item in input_list)
output_list = []
for type, obj_id in identifiers:
    output_list.append({
        'type': type,
        'obj_id': obj_id,
        'actor': [item['actor'] for item in input_list
            if item['type'] is type and item['obj_id'] is obj_id]
        })
```

Alternatively, make use of tuples as dictionary keys:

```
actors_dict = {}
for item in input_list:
    actors_dict.setdefault((item['type'], item['obj_id']), []).append(item['actor'])
output_list = [{'type': type, 'obj_id': obj_id, 'actor': actors}
    for (type, obj_id), actors in actors_dict.iteritems()]
```

Or a more flexible way of writing this (e.g. in case you add other values to be merged) would be:

```
output_dict = {}
for item in input_list:
    k = item['type'], item['obj_id']
    if k in output_dict:
        output_dict[k]['actor'].append(item['actor'])
    else:
        item['actor'] = [item['actor']]
        output_dict[k] = item
output_list = output_dict.values()
```

(Note that this last one will also alter the input list.)